# Seat reservations and check if seats are available

Tags: java, bluej

This is a school project. I have finished most of it, but I am stuck on something.

Here's what I have done till now:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class train1
{
  public static void main() throws IOException
  {
    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader x=new BufferedReader(isr);
    int tp=0, c=0, no=0, r, o;
    boolean flag = true;
    boolean ar[][]=new boolean[10][4];
    System.out.print("***********WELCOME TO TICKET RESERVATION SYSTEM***********");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("                TICKET RESERVATION");
    while(no<10 && flag==true)
        {
    System.out.println("                   Main Menu");
    System.out.println("1. Book Ticket");
    System.out.println("2. Exit");
    System.out.print("Enter Choice   :");
    int choice = Integer.parseInt(x.readLine());
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:

          System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("*********TRAIN TICKET RESERVATION COUNTER***********");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Enter the number for the station as given in the menu below");
                System.out.println("1 for Station A");
                System.out.println("2 for Station B");
                System.out.println("3 for Station C");
                System.out.println("4 for Station D");
                System.out.println("5 for Station E");


                System.out.print("START STATION: ");
                int s=Integer.parseInt(x.readLine());
                System.out.print("DESTINATION STATION: ");
                int d=Integer.parseInt(x.readLine());
                s=--s;
                d=--d;
               **//Here how do I check if seats are available or not?**
                int f=0;
        String starttime="", reaching="";
           if(s==0 && d==1)
            {

                f = 50;
                starttime = "08:00";
                reaching = "10:00";
            }
                 if(s==0 && d==2)
            {
                int a =0;
                int b =2;
                f = 100;
                starttime = "08:00";
                reaching = "12:00";
            }
            if(s==0 && d==3)
            {

                f = 150;
                starttime = "08:00";
                reaching = "14:00";
            }
             if(s==0 && d==4)
            {
                int a =0;
                int b =4;
                f = 200;
                starttime = "08:00";
                reaching = "16:00";
            }
             if(s==1 && d==2)
            {

                f = 50;
                starttime = "10:00";
                reaching = "12:00";
            }
             if(s==1 && d==3)
            {

                f = 100;
                starttime = "10:00";
                reaching = "14:00";
            }
             if(s==1 && d==4)
            {

                f = 150;
                starttime = "10:00";
                reaching = "16:00";
            }
             if(s==2 && d==3)
            {

                f = 50;
                starttime = "12:00";
                reaching = "14:00";
            }
             if(s==2 && d==4)
            {

                f = 100;
                starttime = "12:00";
                reaching = "16:00";
            }
             if(s==3 && d==4)
            {

                f = 50;
                starttime = "14:00";
                reaching = "16:00";
            }
           if (s==4 || d==0)
           {
             System.out.println ("Wrong Choice. Your ticket was not booked");

            }

                for (int i=0; i<no; i++)
                {
                    for (int j=s; j<=d; j++)
                    {
                        ar[i][j]=true;
                    }
                }

                /*
                Now what I have been unable to do is. Suppose a person
                is going from station A to B. Then row 1 column 1 is
                true, and if the next passenger wants to book from B-D
                then how do I get the seat booked in the row 1 if there
                is space available. And is seat is not available then
                it should go to row 2. How do I do that? What I am
                doing is "no++" so it goes to row next every time
                */


                    System.out.print("ENTER THE NAME: ");
                    String people=x.readLine();
                    System.out.print("ENTER THE AGE: ");
                    int age=Integer.parseInt(x.readLine());
                    System.out.print("GENDER OF THE PERSON: ");
                    String gender=x.readLine();
                    System.out.print("DATE OF JOURNRY: ");
                    String date2=x.readLine();

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("      *****RESERVATION TICKET*****");

                    System.out.println("Name :"+people+"     "+"Age :"+age+"      "+"Gender :"+gender+"       ");




            System.out.println();
                System.out.println("START STATION: "+s);
                System.out.println("Boarding time: " + starttime);
                System.out.println("DESTINATION STATION: "+d);
                System.out.println("Expected time of Arrival:" + reaching);
                System.out.println();
           System.out.println("TOTAL AMOUNT: "+ f);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(" ***WISH YOU A HAPPY AND SAFE JOURNEY***");
                System.out.println("COURTESY: ROMIT RAILWAY STATION");


                break;


                case 2:
                flag=false;
                System.out.println ("You have exited");
                break;
                default: System.out.println("Choice Does not Exit");


    }
    no=no++;
}
}
```

Let me tell how it must work. Main Menu must contain 2 options one to book and one to exit. I have done that. Now we need to enter boarding and destination which I have done if booking is selected.

Now the program must check that if seats are available. This is where I am stuck. I have created a 2D array in which I am taking 10 rows and 4 columns. Whenever a ticket is booked I am storing it as true and initially all the places are false. Now whenever a new ticket is booked there will be a change in in the state of array. I have done that too.

What I have been unable to do is: suppose a person is going from station A to B. Then row 1 column 1 is true, and if the next passenger want to book from B-D then how do I get the seat booked in the row 1 if there is space available. And is seat is not available then it should go to row 2. How do I do that?

Also if all the seats are filled then it must show me that seats are not available. How do I do that? I don't know Java very well because I use BlueJ. So it would be better if someone can give suggessions on BlueJ.

I am a class 10 student so please don't bother with SQL system.

Comment: Please post you code here (and do not link to it). Additionally, please try to make clear what parts you have a problem with.

Comment: One possibility is to use some storage using `"stationA - stationB"` (or better a `Route` object with the 2 stations as field and proper `equals`/`hashcode`) as key (think `java.util.Map`) and the `boolean[][]` as value (represents seats used for the `Route`). The difficulty would then be to store somehow possibles routes.

Comment: Can I get a program fragment????

Answer (score 3):

Your first question, about A-B and B-D can not be answered with your data structure because you store a ticket by station (start, intermediate and destination). To solve this you could switch to a data structure that not uses stations, but trajectories (ie AB, BC, CD, etc). You would then need to translate the user input ('from A to B' will become 'trajectory 1 (AB)', and 'from B to D' becomes 'trajectories 2 (BC) and 3 (CD)', now there's no overlap).

To address your other questions, you will have to re-think what you do with the 'no' variable. First of all it doesn't make sense (from what I can tell) to have your loop at line 126 run from 0 every time, you only book one ticket, and in your current code you book seat number stored in `no`. So you only need to set that index of your array (but for every station / trajectory, of course).

Instead of simply incrementing `no` in every loop, you will have to inspect your data structure after the user input, to determine if there is a seat index (first dimension of your array) for which there is still space on all the stations (or trajectories) the user requests. If so, book that, if not: there's no seat available.

(edit: hint: you should not do this with another gigantic if statement, but instead solve this with `for` loops, a few simple `if` statements and probably one or more boolean variables to keep track of results. You may also look into `break` and perhaps even `continue`, which are useful statements to use inside `for` loops.)

(alternatively, you could check for every trajectory if there is any seat available: there will be more chance the user can book a ticket, but he/she may have to switch seats....).

As a sidenote, for bonus points: the big part of your code are if statements that convert start and stop stations (`s` and `d`) into `f` (fare), starttime and stoptime. What happens to the length of your code if you have 10 stations? It explodes because you would need 81 if statements! There is an easier way to do this. Hint: compare for each case `d - s` with the fee. Do you see a pattern? Now compare the `d` to the starttime. Do you see a pattern? Same for `s`. See if you can simplify your code so that it seems doable to ('in the future') expand to 10 stations without writing *a lot* of code.

Comment: also wht do u suggest with 'no'

Comment: Draw 5 letters on a piece of paper with lines in between: A---B---C---D---E. Now the letters are the stations. The --- are the trajectories. You are saying: a user books from A to B, so he needs a reservation for A and B, I'm saying: a user only books the --- *in between* A and B, I have called that trajectory AB in my answer.

Comment: and how do i make the program book in row 1 if seats are available?

Comment: I'm referring to line 126 in your pastebin. I'm suggesting that you drop `no` as a 'global' variable. Instead you determine `no` based on your array for *every* reservation (or even for every trajectory in every reservation).

Comment: In your code, ar[0][0] means 'seat 0, station A', and ar[0][1] means 'seat 0, station B'. What I suggest, is that you change your program so that ar[0][0] means 'seat 0, trajectory AB (ie from A to B)' and ar[0][1] means 'seat 0, trajectory BC'. So, for the first booking (A to B), only ar[0][0] becomes true, then for the second booking (B to D), ar[0][1] and ar[0][2] can become true. Now both use seat 0.

Comment: what you say makes total sense....I understand...but when what should be i - ???  and how do i change the rows ??? The rows limit must be 10.

Comment: I got it how to make that AB, BC thing

Comment: What do you mean with rows? `i` (referring to your pastebin's line 126) and `no` are now simply the same thing: the seat number that has been found available for all trajectories the customer wants to take.

Comment: What do you mean with rows?

Comment: for (int i=0; i<no; i++)
                {
                    for (int j=s; j<=d; j++)
                    {
                        ar[i][j]=true;
                    }
                } now what should be i

Comment: Well, as far as I have understood your data structure (number of seats by stations/trajectories), that becomes `for (int j=s; j<=d; j++) { ar[no][j]=true; }`

Comment: now my question is how to make the change in the form of no....i mean when it finds that no=0 is unavailable how does it change to no=1.

Comment: In short: you can simply do `no = no + 1`. But maybe I can give you a few more hints. First, be sure that 'making' the reservation (ie setting `ar` fields to true) is a separate piece of code that comes *after* the piece that determines what seat is available (if any). That you still need to write: for starters try and think of a way to print for every seat if it is available for trajectory AB. Now do not print but store the first available seat in `no`. From there, the only challenge left is to not simply check for trajectory AB, but to check for all trajectories that the customer requested.

Comment: What I have done now is I am making the full ar to false. Then whenever a seat is booked that will change into true. Now in another for loop I am checking that whenever a book request is done then I make it check is any false is available in the given array. If available it breaks otherwise it does ++n. But my questions are suppose a person books A-B so it gets booked in row 1 and now A-E in row 2 and the 3rd customer wants from C-D so How do I store it in row 1? and if i need seats for 3 stations how do i check false in a row for 3 stations?

Comment: Well, for the first customer `no` becomes 0, for the second it becomes 1, and for the first it becomes 0. Like I said before, you determine `no` (btw: I'm using your variable names, but in general it is 'nicer' to have a bit more descriptive names) again for *every* booking.

Comment: so that mean i turn no=0 everytime ri8?

Comment: As for 'how do I check false in a row for 3 stations': you will need a loop that loops over the required stations (you already have such a loop, simply copy/paste), and a local boolean `isSeatTaken` that starts 'false' before the loop and is set to true inside the loop when you find a 'true'. After the loop, you can check `if ( isSeatTaken ) ` or `if ( ! isSeatTaken )` and do your thing.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would implement it as a for loop that starts checking at seat 0 every time (if you have a *lot* of seats, that may take too long, but that's a challenge that I would say falls way outside the scope of this assignment).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I worked on after getting the suggestions....

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 class Train
{
 public static void main() throws IOException
 {
InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader x=new BufferedReader(isr);
int tp=0, c=0, no=0, r, o, i, count=0, position=0;
boolean flag = true;
boolean ar[][]=new boolean[10][4];
for (int row=0; row<10; row++)
{
    for (int column=0; column<4; column++)
    {
        ar[row][column]=false;
    }
}
System.out.print("***********WELCOME TO TICKET RESERVATION SYSTEM***********");
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("                TICKET RESERVATION");
while(flag==true)
    {
System.out.println("                   Main Menu");
System.out.println("1. Book Ticket");
System.out.println("2. Exit");
System.out.print("Enter Choice   :");
int choice = Integer.parseInt(x.readLine());
switch (choice)
{
    case 1:

      System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("*********TRAIN TICKET RESERVATION COUNTER***********");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter the number for the station as given in the menu below");
            System.out.println("1 for Station A");
            System.out.println("2 for Station B");
            System.out.println("3 for Station C");
            System.out.println("4 for Station D");
            System.out.println("5 for Station E");


            System.out.print("START STATION: ");
            int s=Integer.parseInt(x.readLine());
            System.out.print("DESTINATION STATION: ");
            int d=Integer.parseInt(x.readLine());
            int stat=d-s;
            s=--s;
            d=--d;

                while (no<10)
                {
                for (i=0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    if (ar[no][i]==false)
                    {
                        count=count+1;
                        position=i;
                    }
                }
                 if (count>=stat)
                 {
                   for (int j=position-stat+1; j<position; j++)
                   {
                      ar[no][j]=true;
                   }

                }
                if (count<stat)
                {
                    no=no+1;
                }
                count=0;
                no=0;
            }
    if (no>=10)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {

           int f=0;
    String starttime="", reaching="";
       if(s==0 && d==1)
        {

            f = 50;
            starttime = "08:00";
            reaching = "10:00";
        }
             if(s==0 && d==2)
        {
            int a =0;
            int b =2;
            f = 100;
            starttime = "08:00";
            reaching = "12:00";
        } 
        if(s==0 && d==3)
        {

            f = 150;
            starttime = "08:00";
            reaching = "14:00";
        }
         if(s==0 && d==4)
        {
            int a =0;
            int b =4;
            f = 200;
            starttime = "08:00";
            reaching = "16:00";
        }
         if(s==1 && d==2)
        {

            f = 50;
            starttime = "10:00";
            reaching = "12:00";
        }
         if(s==1 && d==3)
        {

            f = 100;
            starttime = "10:00";
            reaching = "14:00";
        }
         if(s==1 && d==4)
        {

            f = 150;
            starttime = "10:00";
            reaching = "16:00";
        }
         if(s==2 && d==3)
        {

            f = 50;
            starttime = "12:00";
            reaching = "14:00";
        }
         if(s==2 && d==4)
        {

            f = 100;
            starttime = "12:00";
            reaching = "16:00";
        }
         if(s==3 && d==4)
        {

            f = 50;
            starttime = "14:00";
            reaching = "16:00";
        }
       if (s==4 || d==0)
       {
         System.out.println ("Wrong Choice. Your ticket was not booked");

        }
                System.out.print("ENTER THE NAME: ");
                String people=x.readLine();
                System.out.print("ENTER THE AGE: ");
                int age=Integer.parseInt(x.readLine());
                System.out.print("GENDER OF THE PERSON: ");
                String gender=x.readLine();
                System.out.print("DATE OF JOURNRY: ");
                String date2=x.readLine();

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("      *****RESERVATION TICKET*****");

                System.out.println("Name :"+people+"     "+"Age :"+age+"      "+"Gender :"+gender+"       ");




        System.out.println();
            System.out.println("START STATION: "+s);
            System.out.println("Boarding time: " + starttime);
            System.out.println("DESTINATION STATION: "+d);
            System.out.println("Expected time of Arrival:" + reaching);
            System.out.println();
       System.out.println("TOTAL AMOUNT: "+ f);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(" ***WISH YOU A HAPPY AND SAFE JOURNEY***");
            System.out.println("COURTESY: ROMIT RAILWAY STATION");
            }

            break;


            case 2:
            flag=false;
            System.out.println ("You have exited");
            break;
            default: System.out.println("Choice Does not Exit");
     }
         }
       }
        }
```

Comment: this program is not working. The execute stops after i enter destination station. What is my mistake this time?

Comment: By the looks of it, `no` always ends up being 10 after your while loop, which triggers your `if (no>=10)` and breaks your most outer while loop.

Comment: how do I fix this then?